# How to initialise a register to a random value in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am using a clock toggle circuit in the design. Here is the behavioural model of the cell.

```
module toggle (En, CP, Q);
   input CP, En ;
   output Q;

   reg Q_int;

 `ifdef INIT
  initial Q_int = 1'b0;
 `endif

   always @ (posedge CP) begin
     if (En) Q_int <= ~Q_int;
   end

   assign Q = Q_int;

endmodule
```

During my simulations, I am currently initialising `Q_int` to zero using an `ifdef`.  However, this is not covering the true behavior completely.  As long as `Q` changes its state, it doesn't matter where it starts (0 or 1).  How can I initialise `Q_int` to ZERO or ONE for simulation purposes?

How can I achieve some thing like this:

```
Q_int = random(0 or 1)
```

in Verilog or SystemVerilog ?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), section 18.13.2 `$urandom_range()` function.  Passing it a single argument of 1 will randomly return a 0 or 1.  When I pass miscellaneous seed values to my simulator command (VCS or Incisive), I get random initial values assigned to `Q_int`.

```
module toggle (En, CP, Q);
   input CP, En ;
   output Q;

   reg Q_int;

  initial Q_int = $urandom_range(1);

   always @ (posedge CP) begin
     if (En) Q_int <= ~Q_int;
   end

   assign Q = Q_int;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
 $random(seed_value) % 2...
```

The seed value is important as in case you want to reproduce the same output you can by inputting the same seed value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems good and it should initialize Q_int to 0, but make it sure that you are passing "INIT" in your command line.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems like simple,

```
module toggle (En, CP, Q);
   input CP, En ;
   output Q;

   reg Q_int;

  // initial Q_int = $urandom_range(1,0);

  // initial Q_int = $random();

   always @ (posedge CP) begin
     if (En) Q_int <= ~Q_int;
   end

   assign Q = Q_int;

endmodule
```

both commented statement can be used.
$random will generate 32-bit value from RNG of system according to seed value, as your RHS is 1-bit it only assign LSB, in case of $urandom_range, it'll generate random number from specified range only, 0 to 1, it is also depended on seed value.